# Why does my system constantly freeze/jitter when I access my NTFS external hard drive?

Tags: usb, hard-drive, ntfs

I've been trying to figure this out on my own to no avail. I recently purchased a USB 3.0 4TB external hard drive. However, whenever I write or read it the system slows down dramatically. Everything will stutter, key presses only sometimes work, all while my CPU usage stays under 30%. I've tried adjusting my `dirty_ratio` and `dirty_background` ratio, but that didn't seem to make a difference. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

`fdisk -l` listed below:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB          
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 574C1F30-5230-4ABB-B11A-AF5E9C285985

Device             Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      2048   1085439   1083392   529M Windows recovery environment
/dev/nvme0n1p2   1085440   1290239    204800   100M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p3   1290240   1323007     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/nvme0n1p4   1323008 178053119 176730112  84.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/nvme0n1p5 178055168 700418047 522362880 249.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p6 700418048 976773119 276355072 131.8G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD10EZEX-60W
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 99A4A370-A1BC-4D5B-8E50-DC3965C87A3F

Device      Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda5  204800 1953521663 1953316864 931.4G Microsoft basic data

Disk /dev/sdc: 3.7 TiB, 4000787029504 bytes, 7814037167 sectors
Disk model: Expansion Desk  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 87E5CE13-721D-40FB-8B50-BF3FEBE42E43

Device      Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1      34     262177     262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdc2  264192 7814035455 7813771264  3.7T Microsoft basic data

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

Comment: Does the external drive have its own AC power supply? Do you have access to a POWERED USB hub?

Comment: The external drive is plugged into a surge protector, along with my pc and monitor. I don't have access to a USB hub, could that be the issue?

Comment: So the external drive case DOES have its own AC adapter, and that's plugged into a surge protector, correct? Is the drive plugged into a USB 3.x port on the computer? Do you have Windows, and if so, does the drive work properly there? Does the drive have a NTFS partition, or something else?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo fdisk -l` (or `sudo parted -l`) and a screenshot of the `Disks` application SMART Data window for the SDB? drive.

Comment: @heynnema That's correct. It is plugged into a surge protector via it's own AC adapter and is connect via USB 3.x. I tried windows, and got the same stuttering effect. The external drive is an NTFS partition, while my main OS is ext4. I also have a INTERNAL NTFS drive, however I don't encounter this problem with it.

Comment: Two questions... I still need to see the screenshot of the SMART Data window for /dev/sdc. Also, did you begin to use the drive as it came out of the box, or did you initialize it yourself and lay down a fresh gpt partition table and ntfs partition? sdc1 is not properly aligned.

Comment: Side note... have you checked for firmware updates for your Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB?

Comment: @heynnema The option for SMART Data was unavailable. (it was greyed out). Sorry, I completely forgot to mention that. I used the drive out of the box, as is. I have not checked for firmware updates. Will re-partitioning to 'properly align it fix the problem?

Comment: Before I make my recommendations... when you tried to get the SMART Data, had you selected the appropriate disk in the left column in the `Disks` app? Also, do you have Windows on your computer (or another computer)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I selected the Seagate 4TB Drive. I have Windows on my computer (running a windows/ubuntu dual boot).

Comment: Give me a couple of minutes, and I'll put together a quick answer for you. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it, ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently SMART Data is not available from your external 4TB HDD. So we're a little blind to the problem... but we'll approach it a different way.

- **backup any important data from the 4TB HDD**
- boot into Windows
- open a `command` window in admin mode
- assuming that the 4TB drive appears as drive E: (adjust if need be):

  - `chkdsk /f E:` # check file structure
  - `chkdsk /r E:` # bad block the drive, do NOT abort this, this will take MANY hours
- reboot into Ubuntu and retest the drive and see if it still stutters/etc.

If the problem still occurs...

Assuming that the drive appears as /dev/sdc (adjust if need be):

- start `gparted`
- select /dev/sdc (or whatever the correct drive is... be carefull)
- in the Devices menu, select to lay down a fresh GPT partition table (**THIS WILL WIPE THE DRIVE**)
- create a new NTFS or ext4 partition

  - use NTFS if you wish to share files between Windows and Ubuntu
  - use ext4 if you only wish to use the HDD in Ubuntu
- retest again, looking for stutters/etc.

Postnote:

- check for firmware updates for your Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 500GB
- go to the Samsung web site and download their `Samsung Magician` software to check this

**Update #1:**

Part 2 of my answer is what solved the problem. A fresh GPT partition table, and a fresh new ntfs partition.

Comment: Testing this out. Like you said it's taking a while. I'll get back to you when I'm finished!

Comment: Thank you! After reformatting that fixed the issue.

Comment: @TomasBulk just to clarify... did the bad blocking solve the problem... or the fresh GPT partition table and new partition? Thanks!

Comment: Fresh GPT partition table was what did the trick for me!

Comment: @TomasBulk remember to check your SSD firmware.

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the Samsung Magician software and updated the firmware. Thank you for all your help!